# my image is not placed correctly using grid

Tags: html, css, web, grid

I'm working on a website project and I encountered a problem, where I need to make my website responsive so I'm recreating it with 'grid' to make it easier for me, and now I'm facing a new problem where my grid-template-areas is not working (when I try to put the element in the desired column/row it automatically puts it in the wrong place), now, I've checked my syntax and checked for other errors and stuff, but nothing seemed off so. The desired grid layout:
I have a div that contains four cards (divs) and I'm using grid to put every two cards in one line, and it worked, after that I need to make every card layout to be like the following: four rows and three columns, where I have an image and some text in the first row and other text in the other rows, after inserting the image and all, the 'grid' is automatically creating a new column and puting the image there at the bottom of the card when I wanted it to be at the top-middle if the card. here is the code. CSS:

```
#services {
  width: 100%;
  height: 126%;
  background-color: #2d2e2e;
  position: absolute;
  top: 210%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    "first second"
    "fourth third";
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(250px, 1fr));
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
}

.card {
  width: 60%;
  height: 80%;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#card1 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-areas:
    "first second third"
    "fourth fifth sixth"
    "seventh eighth ninth"
    "tenth eleventh twelvth"
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(250px, 1fr));
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
  grid-area: first;
}

#hundred {
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  grid-area: second;
}

#card2 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-areas:
    "first second third"
    "fourth fifth sixth"
    "seventh eighth ninth"
    "tenth eleventh twelvth"
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(250px, 1fr));
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
  grid-area: second;
}

#card3 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-areas:
    "first second third"
    "fourth fifth sixth"
    "seventh eighth ninth"
    "tenth eleventh twelvth"
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(250px, 1fr));
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
  grid-area: third;
}

#card4 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-areas:
    "first second third"
    "fourth fifth sixth"
    "seventh eighth ninth"
    "tenth eleventh twelvth"
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(250px, 1fr));
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
  grid-area: fourth;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="services">
      <div id="card1" class="card">
        <img src="100.png" alt="InternetSpeedTest" id="hundred">
      </div>
      <div id="card2" class="card">

      </div>
      <div id="card3" class="card">

      </div>
      <div id="card4" class="card">

      </div>
    </div>
```

[image: red -> grid layout || blue -> area the image should be in || yellow marker -> the image]

I want the image (marked in yellow) to be in the blue area (the white card's grid layout should be the same as the red lines that I drew) and the image should be in the blue area (top-middle) what could the problem be?

Comment: Please use your browser's devtools inspect facility to check what CSS is actually being applied. You will see that card1 has an invalid value for he grid-templae-areas and that is because there is a missing semicolon. Also you have two definitions of the columns - decide which one is correct.

Comment: Voting to close as seems to have been primarily caused by a typo.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that since I used a nested grid layout I named the grid-template-areas columns and rows the same thing so I just changed that and it worked